# RAID1 Hard drives with Intel Controller

Tags: raid1

I have an older server with 2 35GB hard drives arranged as a RAID-1 drive.  I have 3 open bays, I'd like to add 2 more hard drives to the open bays and have all 4 drives configured as a RAID-1 drive that Windows sees as 1 larger drive.

Is this possible?

If not, the new drives are 2x as big as the old drives, is it possible to replace 1 of the old drives and rebuild then replace the second drive and rebuild and somehow expand the array to use all of the available space?

The server is using an Intel hardware raid controller, the software interface is Intel Storage Console v2.12.

Answer (score 1):

You could, theoretically, configure it as a mirrored pairs and then concatenate the disks.  How possible this is will depend on the exact model (and revision) of the unspecified Intel card you're using.